# what is ModuleID on OpenEJB

Tags: ejb, openejb

i deploy EJBs jar into OpenEJB remote mode but my client can't lookup EJB [EJBs deployed Correctly] , after debugging project i found that openejb.client.moduleid must have value.
but what's is moduleid and how can i set this property ?

Answer (score 1):

The `openejb.client.moduleid` is for Java EE App Client usage.  That ID refers to the ID of the App Client (specified in the META-INF/application-client.xml) and not the id of any particular EJB module deployed.  That said, avoid Java EE App Clients and do not set `openejb.client.moduleid`.

It should be as simple as using the JNDI names printed to the log output when the app is deployed.

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class HelloBean implements Hello {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!!!!";
    }
}
```

Then when you deploy that you should see output like this from the deployer:

```
dblevins@mingus:~/projects$ $OPENEJB_HOME/bin/openejb deploy hello.jar
Application deployed successfully at "hello.jar"
App(id=/home/dblevins/projects/hello.jar)
    EjbJar(id=hello.jar, path=/home/dblevins/projects/hello.jar)
        Ejb(ejb-name=HelloBean, id=HelloBean)
            Jndi(name=HelloBeanRemote)
```

And this in the log

```
2011-06-27 16:21:58,187 - INFO  - Configuring enterprise application: /home/dblevins/projects/hello.jar
2011-06-27 16:21:58,191 - INFO  - Enterprise application "/home/dblevins/projects/hello.jar" loaded.
2011-06-27 16:21:58,191 - INFO  - Assembling app: /home/dblevins/projects/hello.jar
2011-06-27 16:21:58,193 - INFO  - Jndi(name=HelloBeanRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=HelloBean)
2011-06-27 16:21:58,206 - INFO  - Created Ejb(deployment-id=HelloBean, ejb-name=HelloBean, container=My Stateless Container)
2011-06-27 16:21:58,206 - INFO  - Deployed Application(path=/home/dblevins/projects/hello.jar)
```

And the client can lookup the bean using the `Jndi(name=HelloBeanRemote)` information like so:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ejbd://127.0.0.1:4201");

        Context initialContext = new InitialContext(props);

        Hello hello = (Hello) initialContext.lookup("HelloBeanRemote");

        System.out.println(hello.sayHello());
    }
}
```